# How to add two values from a single field with AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

XML field `DISCAMT` is added multiple times using varying values and I'm interested to total these and show in one line. What function can be used here or just create new field/s per each product purchased (`DISCAMT2`, `DISCAMT3`) in the API and use an add function.

EX:

```
DISCAMT="3.50"
DISCAMT="4.00"
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the XML that you are referencing?

Answer (score 2):

If your XML was something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cart>
      <items>
            <item>
                  <sku><![CDATA[123]]></sku>
                  <discAmt>0.1</discAmt>
            </item>
            <item>
                  <sku><![CDATA[456]]></sku>
                  <discAmt>0.2</discAmt>
            </item>
            <item>
                  <sku><![CDATA[789]]></sku>
                  <discAmt>0.3</discAmt>
            </item>
      </items>
</cart>
```

Then you could loop through the nodes in your XML and use the [**add**](https://ampscript.guide/add) function to keep a running total of the `dsctAmt` values.

```html
%%[

var @xml, @isXML, @nodes, @rowCount
set @xml = AttributeValue("xml")

if indexOf(@xml,"<cart>") > 0 then

  set @nodes = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"/cart/items/item",0)
  set @rowCount = rowcount(@nodes)

  if @rowCount > 0 then

    var @totalDiscAmt 
    set @totalDiscAmt = 0

    for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

      var @nodepath
      var @sku
      var @discAmt

      set @discAmt = 0

      set @nodepath = concat("/cart/items/item[",@i,"]/")

      if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"sku"))) > 0 then
          set @sku = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"sku"),0),1),'Value')
      endif

      if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"discAmt"))) > 0 then
          set @discAmt = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"discAmt"),0),1),'Value')
          set @totalDiscAmt = add(@totalDiscAmt,@discAmt)
      endif

      if not empty(@sku) then

      ]%%

       <br>sku: %%=v(@sku)=%% %%=v(@discAmt)=%%</a>

      %%[

      endif

    next @i

    ]%%

     <br><br>totalDiscAmt: %%=v(@totalDiscAmt)=%% <br>

    %%[

  else

   outputline(concat("<br>no products found"))

  endif

else

  outputline(concat("<br>no XML found"))

endif

]%%
```

Comment: XML feeds into field "XML_Data" off the DE 
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Email><ClientInformation 
DISCNAME="10_percent_discount_" DISCQTY="1" DISCAMT="3.5"DISCNAME="10_percent_discount_" DISCQTY="1" DISCAMT="4"

Are you proposing to wrap with 

if indexOf(@xml,"<Email>") > 0 then
etc..

Comment: I'm not suggesting any particular XML structure, just providing an example of doing the math.  SFMC is fine with valid XML, but you're limited to XPATH 1.0 specifications in the BuildRowSetFromXML function.